# Passing array as argument to enum constructor: syntax issues

Tags: java, enums

I am creating an enigma simulation program for some practice with enums. 
The following is a preliminary draft for the enum of a machine, so I don't have any of the specifics, yet.

The issue is that my IDE keeps saying that the curly braces are not supposed to be there, at the point I am trying to pass an array into the enum constructor.

Is there something wrong with my enum constructor or the enum constant declaration? How can I correct this to make it work?

```
public enum MACHINETYPE {
    WehrmachtEnigma (4, {true, true, true, false}),
    KriegsmarineM4(4, {true, true, true, true}),
    Abwehr(4, {true, true, true, true});

    private final int ROTORS_COUNT;
    private final boolean[] STEPPING;

    private MACHINETYPE(int rotors, boolean[] stepping){
        ROTORS_COUNT = rotors;
        STEPPING = stepping;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized that, after I had answered this question, I had answered it *before*.  Sorry about that.

Comment: This question is not just about array initialisation but about passing arrays as arguments. It doesn't look like a true duplicate of [Array initialisation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139977/array-initialisation-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring your arrays properly. They should be declared using `new boolean[] { ... }`. However as your arrays are arguments to a constructor you could shorten your declarations by using a varargs notation. This will remove your error message.

```
enum MACHINETYPE{
    WehrmachtEnigma (4, true, true, true, false),
    KriegsmarineM4(4, true, true, true, true),
    Abwehr(4, true, true, true, true);

    private final int ROTORS_COUNT;
    private final boolean[] STEPPING;

    private MACHINETYPE(int rotors, boolean... stepping){
        ROTORS_COUNT = rotors;
        STEPPING = stepping;
    }
}
```